# Is it possible to allow some ROS command lines to be executed automatically when a Raspberry Pi is turned on?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

For example if I want to make the roscore and some launch programs (such as Crazyflie activation launch file or VICON camera launch file....) to automatically executed whenever I turn on the Raspberry Pi. Is it possible? How can I do that?

This is because I have to do this all the time I work on my project, so I want it to be automatic.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260798/is-it-possible-to-allow-some-ros-command-lines-to-be-executed-automatically-when-a-raspberry-pi-is-turned-on?/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look at [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3